# Certificates and Provisioning Profiles with Xcode 8.3.x on Separate Partitions of the Same Computer

Tags: certificate, xcode8, provisioning-profile

I have several partitions on the same computer.  A different macOS version is installed on each of them.  I was developing desktop and iOS applications under **El Capitan** till a week ago.  Then I've decided to completely switched to **Sierra**.  Now, I want to code-sign and send to App Store old and new applications that are maintained under the Sierra partition.  For that goal, I need access to provisioning profiles.

[image]

The problem that I have with the new partition is that I no longer see a list of provisioning profiles.  If I open Xcode's Accounts, I no longer have the view details button.  Instead, I have the manage certificates button.  Clicking on it, I see a list of development and distribution certificates, not a list of provisioning profiles, which kind of tells me that Xcode is confused about which group of certificates to work with.  I have a pair of certificates installed for the new partition (dated 2017/06/19).  But Xcode is still confused, I suppose.  I can't bring certificates from old partition to the new partition.  If I do, the panel shows that certificates don't have private keys.  I CAN go back to the old partition in order to use provisioning profiles.   So how can I access provisioning profiles under the new partition?  Revoking existing certificates on the old partition is the only solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the old certificates with their private keys from the Keychain on your old partition.  Go into Keychain Access, find the iOS Development and iOS Distribution certificates under "My Certificates" and select `File`->`Export Items...` Save the cert with it's private key as a .p12 file.  Then get the .p12 file to your new partition (email, USB drive, direct copy) and import it into your Keychain on the new partition.

The other option is to switch to Xcode 8's automatic code signing.  That would allow Xcode, when signed into your developer account, to create all the code signing assets necessary. Previously, Apple only let you have 2 certificates of each type at any time, which caused problems when letting Xcode manage the certs because creating a cert on a new Mac (or new install of Mac OS X) would often invalidate the cert on the old Mac.  Now, Apple let's you have multple certs, so with automatic code signing, each new Mac (or each instance of Mac OS) can have it's own certificate and provisioning profile.   I would attempt to start using automatic code signing if you no longer need to use Xcode 7.  You can find out more about it [here](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/migrating_code_signing.html#automatic-signing-xcode-8).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Do you mean that I need not create a new set of certificates for the 2nd partition?  Anyway, I'm ready to go to bed.  I'll get back with you in several hours.

Comment: You can either create a new certificate and associated provisioning profile for the second provision, or you can export the existing cert and private key as I mention in the first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks.  After revoking new certificates that I created yesterday, I have imported a bunch of old certificates to the new partition as described here.  But the situation doesn't improve.  I still see the manage certificates button.  If I click on it, I still see the same certificate screen.

Comment: Yes, that is what you should see.  If you imported the certs correctly, you should see the status of the certificates for some should now no longer say "Not in keychain".  If you still see that, you didn't get something right.  If you open the Keychain Access app, you should see you certificates and you should be able to expand them and see the private key underneath.

Comment: Okay.  But if you take a look at the initial screenshot, I did have working certificates.  I've removed them.  Now, I've successfully imported keys to the new partition.  But the button name still remains as Manage Certificates, not View Details.  So how do I go from Manage Certificates to View Details after successfully importing certificates from the 1st partition?  Thanks.

Comment: That screen doesn't exist anymore.  In Xcode 8, you can see the certs.  If you want to see provisioning profiles available on the MAc account you are using, go to `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/`.  Have you clicked the "Download Profiles" button? Are you having problems signing your app? Xcode is not confused - it just changed the way you manage code signing assets. If you don't like the interface in Xcode, simply log into the dev site and manually download the provisioning profile you need.  Double click the .mobileprovision file and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks.  I wish Apple had personally told me by letter they made the change in the way we access provisioning profiles.